# A wordpress site keeps editing wp-content files after migration

Tags: themes

We migrated our clients websites to a new server, just afterwards, a client started calling us upon problems with his website's layout and design (basically, all his wp-content/themes files are automatically updated).

I launched a backup restoration, and I noticed that the website gets back to normal just before the end of restoration.

But once restoration ended successfully, I see that the website's design is again changed.

So, to solve this, I did not check database restoration, which makes the site look normal for about 4 - 5 hours, and it deforms eventually after.

We scanned the website for malware, but in vain.

I don't think personally that it's a cache problem, since cache would not change files like `wp-content/themes/header.php` , whose PHP and HTML code get edited just after 4 - 5 hours.

Do you have an idea what may be the source of this problem?

Thank you

Comment: i think db migration problem please check database .

Comment: please upload old theme file

Comment: use duplicator plugin for site migration

Comment: Thank you so much, unfortunately I cannot do these steps, simply because I am not the owner of the website and I have no right to edit it.

All I can do is restore the backups...  I just wonder if there is a wordpress plugin that edits files automatically.

Comment: Most probably it's an infection. What are these changes?

Comment: the whole file header.php for example is changed to a very old version of the same file. There is no suspicious tags or javascript code.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, although I am a programmer myself, I don't have the right to touch their code. That's why I cannot post any html or javascript here. I was just asking to know possible sources for this problem.

Comment: @SmootQ Are you modifying a 3rd-party theme? If you do that then if the theme is updated you will lose the changes. Use a custom child theme if you want to modify an existing theme.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Thank you for this tip, I am not the owner of the website, I will look into this thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have an issue with parent/child theme overwriting like Jacob Peattie said in the comments.

Another possibility is that your hosting provider is changing something during that restore process. Check your wp-config.php settings to make sure they haven't changed, and check your Settings > General tab in wp-admin to make sure your domain hasn't changed. The WordPress Address (URL) and the Site Address (URL). I know of a few hosting providers who try to convert the site's domain when migrating and restoring backups, and if you have a custom domain setup and this changes from its original value, then your site doesn't know how to find the theme content that is hard linked and located in wp-content. Any relative links would still work if the base domain changed, but any hard links would have been broken.
(This might be hard to check if you don't have access to any root files)

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, I am not the site owner, I am just in charge of migrating our clients' websites to another server, and this single wordpress website turned to be the only case where this happened. I will check if it is using a child theme, and contact the client and refer him to your answer, thank you so much again !

Comment: haha, well you don't have to accept my answer as 'correct' with the green checkmark until you actually figure out the issue.

Comment: Yes you are right, I just meant to +1 , thank you , I am 70% sure that this is the problem as I can't conceive of any other reason. Best !